# Azure logic app timeout when your triggering function app

Tags: web-scraping, webhooks, azure-logic-apps, xls, azure-function-app

ideally need to extract all the invoice in xls format of website, storing in SharePoint. I am using Docker for pulling the python code, firefox, and gecko driver.
when i call the logic app http trigger it gives the timeout error but all the invoices can store in the Sharepoint logic app ran and gives failed.
within 2 min limit, gives succeeded results (trigger history fired).

I am using HTTP trigger and function app URL.

how to use Webhook or any other solution to call long-running logic app successful results.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use "[HTTP Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook#add-an-http-webhook-action)" in your logic app. But you also need to modify your function code. [Here](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTriggersExample) provide a sample of the code for your reference. The sample is not a azure function, but you can refer to it to modify your function code. Please pay attention to the below [code](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTriggersExample/blob/master/LogicAppTriggers/Controllers/WebhookTriggerController.cs) of the sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace LogicAppTriggers.Controllers
{
    public class WebhookTriggerController : ApiController
    {
        public static List<string> subscriptions = new List<string>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Recieve a subscription to a webhook.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="callbackUrl">URL to get from Logic Apps - @listCallbackUrl()</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost, Route("api/webhooktrigger/subscribe")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe([FromBody] string callbackUrl)
        {
            subscriptions.Add(callbackUrl);
            return Request.CreateResponse();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Fire all triggers - do a GET to this API to fire all triggers subscribed
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet, Route("api/webhooktrigger/trigger")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                foreach (string callbackUrl in subscriptions)
                    await client.PostAsync(callbackUrl, @"{""trigger"":""fired""}", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, String.Format("There are {0} subscriptions fired", subscriptions.Count));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Unsubscribe
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="callbackUrl"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost, Route("api/webhooktrigger/unsubscribe")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Unsubscribe([FromBody] string callbackUrl)
        {
            subscriptions.Remove(callbackUrl);
            return Request.CreateResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use "HTTP Webhook" like below:

[image]