# BadRequest while calling Azure function from logicapp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, timeout, azure-logic-apps

In my logicapp I have configured to trigger a azure function , once the azure function triggered it does the job successfully but in logicapp flow i can see it failed with badrequest (below JPG)

[image]

Error :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits."
  }
}
```

More details of Azure function :

1. Average total runtime 3-5 minutes
2. Written in PowerShell

Comment: Logic App will only wait upto 2mins, and hence timing out, since your total runtime exceeds it. Instead, you could call a HTTP `webhook` from your Logic App. see this [article](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
In your Error Image of Logic App, it shows a [MS Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption,azure-portal#http-limits) i.e., Azure Logic App Limits and Config.

It has been written that there are limits for both inbound and outbound request in Azure Logic App for the Http Requests:

[image]

Also, there is notes section on using the Inbound requests in a Logic App in long runs case.

Thanks to @*AnandSowmithiran* for suggesting the alternative solution to the user with this Jeff Hollan's medium [article](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701).

You can use a HTTP Webhook from the Logic App if it is long running if your total runtime exceeds than the default timeout of Logic app inbound request.

I have found a [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134234/azure-logic-app-timeout-when-your-triggering-function-app) on the same context of Azure Logic App Timeout when function app is triggering where User @*HuryShen* provided how to use the Webhook in an Azure Logic App with sample example.